# Unable to extract text from image

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

I've been working on a project where  use tesseract to extract text from image.I'm also using python 3.7.7 
But I'm getting an error which I can't solve.

```
tess.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tess1\\eng.traineddata'

img = Image.open('C:\\Users\\USER\\PycharmProjects\\selenium\\automation\\screenshot.png')
text = tess.image_to_string(img, lang='eng')
```

When I run this I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/selenium/automation/open.py", line 8, in <module>
    text = tess.image_to_string(img, lang='eng')
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\selenium\venv\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 360, in image_to_string
    }[output_type]()
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\selenium\venv\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 359, in <lambda>
    Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\selenium\venv\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 270, in run_and_get_output
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\selenium\venv\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 241, in run_tesseract
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\selenium\venv\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 238, in run_tesseract
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, **subprocess_args())
  File "C:\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1207, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Please provide a suitable solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Tesseract software installed in the system for you to use pytesseract. pytesseract is just a library that calls the OCR engine Tesseract internally.

### Tesseract Installation

#### For Windows

- [installation link](https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki)

#### adding path to path variable

- [windows 10](https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/add-windows-path-environment-variable/)
- [windows 7](https://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/fot-addpath.html)